# Looping a javascript function and pushing the result into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am at the end of my wits. Maybe somebody can shed some light.
I am essentialy trying to run a function 10x using a for loop and then push the results into an array. However, all I get is ten "undefined" in my array. The actual **resolved value** from the function is not being pushed into array. Does anyone have an idea?

Here's the code

```js
function playGame(){
 var userChoice = getUserChoice('rock');
 var computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
 
  console.log(determineWinner(userChoice,computerChoice));
};

function keepScore () { 
let resultArray = [];

  for(let x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    resultArray.push(playGame(x))
  }
  
   console.log(resultArray); 

};

keepScore();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need a return statement in `playGame()`

Comment: I might add that the function getComputerChoice() generates value. I get ten strings when I run a simple for loop. I get 10x undefiened whenever I try to push em into an array.

Comment: Cheers @RandyCasburn it works now

Comment: `playGame` needs to `return determineWinner(userChoice,computerChoice)` instead of just logging it.

Comment: @Barmar. Ah got it now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This should work. The main thing here is to `return` the value wanted. The added code is just to make the snippet work.

```js
function playGame() {
  var options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor'];
  var userChoice = window.prompt("rock, paper, scissors");
  var computerChoice = options[(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3  + 1) - 1)];
  var arr = [userChoice, computerChoice];
  console.log(userChoice, computerChoice);
  return (arr);
};

function keepScore() {
  var resultArray = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    resultArray.push(playGame(x))
  }
  console.log(resultArray);
};

keepScore();
```

Comment: 3 - 1 + 1? Also known as 3 :) ;) ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you call push, you need to specify an element to be pushed. However, you are calling the play game function which doesn't return any element. You should explicitly specify the element to be returned in the play game and it should work!

```
function playGame(){
 var userChoice = getUserChoice('rock');
 var computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
 
  return determineWinner(userChoice,computerChoice);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `determineWinner(userChoice,computerChoice)`

Right now, the function just returns `undefined`

So, just add `return determineWinner(userChoice,computerChoice);`, and you should be fine.